# Find the constant a so that $(x+y)^a$ is the integrating factor of $(4x^2+2xy+6y)dx+(2x^2+9y+3x)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

${\partial M\over\partial y} = (4x^2+2xy+6y)a(x+y)^{a-1} + (x+y)^a(2x+6)\tag1$

${\partial N\over\partial x} = (2x^2+9y+3x)a(x+y)^{a-1} + (x+y)^a(4x+3)\tag2$

${\partial M\over\partial y} = {\partial N\over\partial x}\tag3$

$$\quad\quad=> 4x^2+2xy+6y = 2x^2+9y+3x\quad\text{ and }\quad2x+6 = 4x+3\tag4$$

$=> x = 3/2, y = 0$

How to find $a$ now?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I took the liberty of numbering your equations so that they could be referred to. Now, I fail to see how (4) follows from (3).

Comment: No reaction to the answer below? Why?

Answer (score 1):

You solve it incorrectly. You can't split the equation the way you did. You have $$\small (4x^2+2xy+6y)a(x+y)^{a-1}+(x+y)^a(2x+6)=(2x^2+9y+3x)a(x+y)^{a-1} + (x+y)^a(4x+3)$$
Dividing by $(x+y)^{a-1}$ we get $$a(4x^2+2xy+6y)+(x+y)(2x+6)=a(2x^2+9y+3x)+(x+y)(4x+3) \\ a(2x^2+2xy-3y-3x)=(x+y)(2x-3) \\ a(2x-3)(x+y)=(x+y)(2x-3) \\ \boxed{a=1}$$